# Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$, prove $\int_a^bfg\le\frac{1}{2}[\int_a^bf^2+\int_a^bg^2]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Not sure what to use here, would like some help. Thank you. These are Riemann integrals also.

My finished proof:

Since $f$ and $g$ are both continuous on $[a,b]$ then we have that $f$ and $g$ are both integrable on $[a,b]$. Using the proofs that $f^2,g^2,-2fg$ are all integrable on $[a,b]$ we have that $(f-g)^2$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and that $(f-g)^2\ge0$ implies:

$\int_a^b(f-g)^2=\int_a^bf^2+g^2-2fg=\int_a^bf^2+\int_a^bg^2-\int_a^b2fg\ge0$

therefore,

$\int_a^bf^2+\int_a^bg^2\ge\int_a^b2fg$

hence,

$\frac{1}{2}(\int_a^bf^2+\int_a^bg^2)\ge\int_a^bfg$

∎

Comment: This is a version of what's called the "AM-GM" inequality, in case you didn't know.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$   (a - b)^2 \ge 0   $$

Comment: ah, would this be a hint towards the polynomial $f^2+g^2+2fg$? seems really obvious now

Comment: @Albert $-2fg$ but yes.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$(f(x) \pm g(x))^2 =f^2(x)+g^2(x) \pm 2f(x)g(x) \ge 0.$

$f^2(x)+g^2(x) \ge 2 |f(x)g(x)|$.

Hence

$f(x)g(x) \le |f(x)g(x)| \le$

$ 2|f(x)g(x)| \le f^2(x)+g(x)^2.$